# valgrind - invalid write size

Tags: size, valgrind, memcpy

we have couple of C applications which talk using the shared memory. first application adds the message and the second one always reads from the shared memory.

```
struct messagestruct {
 unsigned int sessionid;
 uint8_t message[16]; //unsigned 8bit int
}__attribute__ ((__packed__));
```

we need to have 3 sessions (for 3 users). so defined shared memory size as

```
#define SHARED_SIZE ( 3 *  sizeof(messagestruct)) + sizeof(int)
```

we access the shared memory as

```
int sesskey = ftok("/path/to/a/file", "B");
int shmemoryid = shmget(sesskey, SHARED_SIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
```

during copying structs to shared memory, valgrind reports error (invalid write size 1)

```
void *shmaddr = shmat(shmemoryid, NULL, 0);
int *sessnum;
struct messagestruct *msgstruct;
sessnum = (int *)shmaddr;
msgstruct = (struct messagestruct*)((void*) shmaddr + sizeof(int));   
memcpy(shmaddr, currentsessionsstruct, SHARED_SIZE); //-->valgrind error invalid write size 1
```

thanks for any helpful info.

Comment: How big is the memory block you try to write to?

Comment: @Heandel struct messagestruct currentsessionsstruct[3];

Comment: @sharptooth SHARED_SIZE is the size we share between apps. one writes to that memory block & other reads from it. using semaphores to lock & unlock memory segment

Comment: Great, but do you call `shmget()` asking it for enough memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
memcpy(shmaddr, currentsessionsstruct, SHARED_SIZE);
```

You are copying `3 * sizeof(messagestruct) + sizeof(int)`. I believe you want to copy only `sizeof(currentsessionstruct)`.